# how to greet user whenever they interact with chat bot, chat bot should greet the user without waiting for any response from user

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, skypedeveloper

i want to greet user without giving any input to chat bot, usually the chat bot interact with user after getting first response from user, i have integrated the Skype bot in my website, what i actually want is whenever user click on Skype Bubble button , the chat bot should greet the user without waiting for any response from user, any suggestion or advice will be appreciated.
[screen shot of chat bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ8hi.png)
i have used this code in conservationUpdate it did work in emulator but did not work when i deployed it

```
 IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;                            
 var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
            if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
            {
                foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
                {
                    if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        var reply = message.CreateReply();
                        reply.Text = $"Hi, Welcome!";

                        client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: i have added an image  have a look in it. i guess you may get an idea about problem

Comment: Do you want [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages) ?

Comment: Do you want to greet every time or the very first time?

Comment: john proactive messages are good for external service interruption but .. is it possible to manipulate proactive messages to greet user every time when it resume conversation with bot or having a fresh start?

Comment: @EzequielJadib  ... I am looking for both scenario to work firstly, when user interact with bot for first time the bot must greet him "hello user welcome to chatbot etc". Secondly, when user resume again its conversation with bot, the bot should greet user again "welcome back user "

Comment: The skype channel doesn't send ConversationUpdate event when the web page is reloaded.